# How to increase a new type and don't need to modify factory class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

when i'm using factory pattern, i got a question : when i have a new type ,i need to modify my factory class. such as that:

Animal.java:

```
public interface Animal {
    void eat();
}
```

Dog.java:

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
    ...
    @Override
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("eat bones");
    }
}
```

Cat.java

```
public class Cat implements Animal {
    ...
    @Override
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("eat fish");
    }
}
```

Now I have an Animal interface and two Animal classes, then i have my factory here:

```
public class AnimalFactory {
    public static final int Dog = 1;
    public static final int Cat = 2;

    public static Animal getAnimal(int type) {
        switch(type) {
           case Dog: return new Dog();
           case Cat: return new Cat();
           default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It's very simple, but if i have a new type `Mouse` ,I have to modify my factory to add a case statement like `case Mouse: return new Mouse` .

So, it's there a way to in increase new type and don't need to modify my factory class?

Comment: There could be many different implamentations of factory. By this implementation yes you have to modify factory class. OTOH if your factory uses reflection to find and instatiate animals then yiu might not need to change it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I know this is probbably not your desired answer, but this just isn't how to use factories. At least use enums or class references. Anyways ... why'd you not want to have specific methods for each type, any other you'd not have runtime safety.

Comment: I know this question is very low, and I'm weak at it. I just want to know how to do when i  increase a type and I don't need to modify anything, just add a new class.

Comment: @JackyWong which of the Factory patterns do you have in mind? There are many. Do you have a link or a specific source we could look at?

Answer (score 1):

To make a factory with no need to be updated/modified for each `Animal` type added/removed you have to extract the logic of retrieve the `Animal` classes and their factory identifier into the `Animal` classes themselves.
Broadly all animal subclasses should implement a method that returns the identifier for the factory and in the factory you should fist load from a specific package all classes implementing this interfaces. This loading classes would be simpler to do with the [reflections library](http://%60https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections%60).
But implementing it will be neither straight nor safe and reliable at compile time.
To not maintain the factory a better bet would be to use the factory feature provided by a dependency injection framework.
The factory class would be not required any longer.

With Spring, the Dog could be declared as :

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Dog extends Animal{..}
```

Note the prototype scope to indicate that a new instance has to be created at each injection.

And from the client side you could just inject the Animal instance such as :

```
@Autowired
private Dog dog;
```

Or using an explicit factory `Dog dog = ApplicationContext.getBean("dog");`

Answer (score 0):

in your case your factory method currently does not have any complex logic to determine which class should be instantiated and it's object returned - so instead of passing the animal type as an integer constant, you could also pass `java.lang.Class<? extends Animal> animalClass` as a method parameter using **generics** and create the corresponding animal instance of a concrete class by using **reflection** (have a look at `Class.newInstance()`)... this would save you from writing additional code each time you add a new animal type...

Simple example, you might wanna deal with the specific exceptions that can be thrown in the method implementation instead of just throwing all exceptions...

`Class<? extends Animal> animalClass` allows only Class instances passed to your factory method as a parameter which are sub-classes/interface-implementing-classes of Animal.

```
public static Animal getAnimal(Class<? extends Animal> animalClass) throws Exception {
    return animalClass.newInstance(); 
    // >=JAVA9: return animalClass.getDeclaredConstructors().newInstance(); 
}
```

Client code using your factory:

```
Animal animal = AnimalFactory.getAnimal(Dog.class);
```